# How to solve this Deutsch Jozsa variant?

Tags: deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

You are given a function $f : \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$ and a quantum circuit, $C$, computing the signed implementation of $f$. Let $I_0$ be the input bit-strings of length $n$ where the first bit is $0$, and $I_1$ be the
remaining ones (i.e., the first bit is $1$).

You are given the promise that $f$ is one of these two types:

1. $f(x) = 0 $ for all $x$ belonging to $I_0$ and $f(x) = 1$ for all $x$ belonging to $I_1$
2. The total number of strings in $I_0$ for which $f(x) = 1$ plus the total number of strings in $I_1$ for which $f(x)$ is $0$ is $2^{n-1}$.

**Give an algorithm (i.e., quantum circuit) to distinguish between these two cases by calling $C$ only once.**

Comment: Thanks @KAJ226 !!

Comment: Is this a homework problem? If so, please add some of your own work to the bottom

Comment: No it is not. I was reading notes of Ronald de Wolf to brush up my QC concepts and I found this problem. Intrigued by the problem I started solving it but couldn't get any idea on how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like this one!

Hint: Can you transform the function into another one that is closer to the type of functions Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm deals with?

Answer under spoiler, so as not to ruin the fun for others:

> Implement the following phase oracle based on the oracle given for $f(x)$: $g(x) = f(x)$ if $x \in I_0$, and $g(x) = 1 - f(x)$ if $x \in I_1$. You can do that by applying the $f(x)$ oracle and then doing a Z gate on the first qubit.
>  
>  Now you have one of the two cases:
>  
>  1. $g(x) = 0$ for all $x$ (constant!)
>  
>  2. The total number of strings for which $g(x) = 1$ equals $2^{n-1}$ (balanced!)
>  
>  And this is exactly the Deutsch-Jozsa problem!

Comment: Thank you so much @Mariia. That is really an elegant approach !!